# Is it required to use jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer when you are using bzm - Concurrency Thread Group in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, test-plan

Good day!
I'm using JMeter to do load testing. It's my first time to use this tool.
I'm confused with some aspect of JMeter.
I will be using bzm - Concurrency Thread Group to simulate traffic to the server. Based on documentation, it must be required to used it along with jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer.
However, I'm thinking not to use it. Will there be any problem in my during my test?
[bzm - Concurrency Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKqmx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

- Concurrency thread group is responsible for starting/stopping **threads** (you can think of them as of virtual users), like "I want to have 100 concurrent users for 10 minutes"
- Throughput shaping timer is responsible for producing **throughput**, the load in terms of requests per second, like "I want to have 100 requests per second for 10 minutes"

So:

1. When you operate with "users" you cannot guarantee the number of requests per second which will be generated (see [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) for more details if needed)
2. When you operate with "throughput" you cannot guarantee that the number of users will be sufficient for conducting the required load.

So you **don't have to** use the Throughput Shaping Timer, you **can** if you want to reach/maintain the load certain number of requests per second and want to make sure that the number of threads is sufficient as they can be connected via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will be able to kick off some new threads if the current amount is not sufficient for conducing the required load